# Java Statistics Package? (Markov Chains and advanced distributions)

Tags: java, statistics

I'm having trouble searching for a decent Java library that provides Markov chains, and other advanced distributions (as in, statistics).

I've found http://sourceforge.net/projects/hydra-mcmc/   on source forge, and it looks somewhat useable, but does anyone know / use a more up-to-date package? (Haven't really have a trove through this package, but one would assume a more well maintained package would be desirable).

Anyone able to make a suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to interface with R (r-project.org) in the same way that http://jgr.markushelbig.org/JGR.html uses Java to access the R-Language.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a library per say, but it can give you some pointers:

[Java-mcmc](http://www.lbreyer.com/java.html) introduced some sophisticated applets illustrating:

- Common Metropolis-Hastings algorithms
- Coupling constructions for Markov chains

The source code for this web demo of **Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC)** is [available here](http://www.lbreyer.com/mcmc-webdemo.html).

**Other similar projects are [listed there](http://www.martindalecenter.com/Calculators2A_2_A%5A.html)**.